# Unable to access Internet in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, networking, dual-boot

I have a windows OS alongside Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Whenever I plug in the ethernet in the port of my HP laptop, a white light glows indicating a proper connection(This happens when I am in Windows OS). But as soon as I switch to Ubuntu the light disappears and it says Ethernet Network disconnected. Please suggest a remedy. I only have an access to this LAN and if any external driver downloads are required I have to use a USB to transfer the downloads to the Ubuntu OS.

Please give a detailed info as I am new to Linux OS.

Thank You:)

The output of `lspci knn | grep Eth -A3; uname -a`

```
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
      Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device[103c:81ea]
      Kernel device in use: r8169
Linux ubuntu 4.4.0-31-generic #50~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 01:07
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3; uname -a` terminal command.

Comment: I have edited the Q

Answer (score 0):

Download these files to your Home folder

http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/r8168/r8168-dkms_8.041.00-1_all.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04.9_all.deb

and run

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

This will install a vendor driver.